# Build a two-stage Django admin form for adding an object?

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible to build a two-stage form for creating an object in Django admin?

When an admin user visits `/admin/my-app/article/add/`, I'd like to display some options. Then, the app would display the creation page with pre-calculated fields based on the selections made.

Comment: Would it be a problem to save the "partial" item already? If not than you could simply pre-calculate in the save method and return the user to the added item.

Comment: I'd prefer not to because those calculated fields are required, and partial saving would require dropping the model's enforcement of that (I believe?)

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700979/in-django-how-do-i-mimic-the-two-step-method-of-adding-users-through-the-admin-f and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929149/django-admin-site-how-does-the-add-user-page-works-more-fields-on-edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could overwrite the `add_view` method on the `ModelAdmin` ([Source](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L838)) of `myapp.article`. It is responsible for rendering the modelform and adding objects to the database.

While adding your functionality, you likely want to keep the original code intact instead of copying/modifying it.

**Draft**

```
def add_view(self, request, **kwargs):
    if Stage1:
        do_my_stuff()
        return response
    else:
        return super(ModelAdmin, self).add_view(self, request, **kwargs)
```

Now you need to distinguish between the two stages. A parameter in the GET query string could do that. To pass initial data to a form in the admin, you only need to include the fieldname value pairs as parameters in the querystring.

**Draft 2**

```
def add_view(self, request, **kwargs):
    if 'stage2' not in request.GET:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # calculate values
            parameters = 'field1=foo&field2=bar'
            return redirect('myapp_article_add' + '?stage2=1&' + parameters)
        else:
            # prepare form for selections
            return response
    else:
        return super(ModelAdmin, self).add_view(self, request, **kwargs)
```

You probably need to look at the code to return a correct response in your first stage. There are a couple of template variables `add_view` sets, but hopefully this is a good start to look further.